# Trying to maintain Login state with Android SharedPreferences

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I have a class that extends application:

```
public class myApp extends Application {

    public static boolean isUserLoggedIn = false;
    public static String username = null;
    public static SharedPreferences logInState;

    public static boolean userLogin() {

        return myApp.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    }

    public static boolean userLogout() {

        return myApp.isUserLoggedIn = false;
    }

    public static void setUser(String s) {

        myApp.username = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String PREFS_NAME = "LoginState";
        logInState = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

}
```

I feel I am halfway there to simply having a true/false variable to indication whether user needs to log in each time the start the app. Of course, I will store username as well in SharedPreference, but for the sake of this question, I am only discussing one to keep it simple. (Keep in mind, user can start the app w/o login, but function is limited -- they may login through overflow menu).

When the user first logins, I want to get the preference to true.  **How do I call this class extending application from within activity?**

Currently I have this for a successful Login attempt:

```
myApp.userLogin();
myApp.setUser(UsernameLogin);
// would like to set SharedPreference var to true here?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Maintain User Login State first Make one Class Called PreferenceData. When User Logged in Successfully then set one variable true and logged out then false in shared preference.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class PreferenceData 
{
    static final String PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_EMAIL = "logged_in_email";
    static final String PREF_USER_LOGGEDIN_STATUS = "logged_in_status";

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) 
    {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void setLoggedInUserEmail(Context ctx, String email) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_EMAIL, email);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getLoggedInEmailUser(Context ctx) 
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_EMAIL, "");
    }

    public static void setUserLoggedInStatus(Context ctx, boolean status) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_USER_LOGGEDIN_STATUS, status);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static boolean getUserLoggedInStatus(Context ctx) 
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getBoolean(PREF_USER_LOGGEDIN_STATUS, false);
    }

    public static void clearLoggedInEmailAddress(Context ctx) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.remove(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_EMAIL);
        editor.remove(PREF_USER_LOGGEDIN_STATUS);
        editor.commit();
    }   
}
```

Now in activity you can call its method like below.

```
PreferenceData.setUserLoggedInStatus(this,true);   // For set user loggedin status
PreferenceData.getUserLoggedInStatus(this);        // Get User Logged In status . true = login
```

Answer (score 2):

For Maintaining the user Login State with sharedpreference you have to need to Make a Class for user login session Called SessionManager. When User Logged in Successfully then set boolean vairable true and when user become logged out then set that boolean vairable false in shared preference.the class will be like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "IsLogin";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    //public static final String KEY_SITEID = "siteid";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String checklogin, boolean b){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
      //  editor.putString(KEY_NAME, checklogin);

        // Storing email in pref
       // editor.putString(KEY_SITEID, siteid);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }   

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginForm.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
       // user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginForm.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```