# Android Save SharedPreferences from EditText

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-edittext

In my application, I have an `EditText` for the user to enter a text. So, I want to save the text of an `EditText` in `SharedPreferences`. I want the `SharedPreferences` to be updated when the text from editText is changed.

> I am using this code:

```
message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);

final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
          prefs.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

    }
});
```

1. I am not sure, whether to put `prefs.edit().putString("autoSave",
   s.toString()).commit();` in `onTextChanged()` or in afterTextChanged.
2. I tried to put it in both `onTextChanged()`  and afterTextChanged but when I restart the application, there is no text that I edited.

Comment: where you setting Text in ExitText..?

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani means ??? I am allowing user to custom change the text what ever he wants. I am providing my application with text "I am in danger" but he wants he can change it to "Please Help", so for that i want the edited text to get saved .

Comment: You Are saving edited text... But when you load your app, are you loading the save text and putting it back into your text box? plus, its better in `afterTextChanged`

Comment: save it on afterTextChanged.. and you are not displaying it anywhere you just saved it. you need something like message.setText(prefs.getString(autoSave, ""));

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are saving the text fine, but you never load it when you load your application.

Try adding this line to set the text:

```
message.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave", ""));
```

> See full example below

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager 
                                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

message.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave", ""));

message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){

   }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
    prefs.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();
  }

});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. It worked. Can you please tell me just in brief what difference does message.setText(prefs.getString(autoSave, "")); it make ???

Comment: if probably you can guide me, will be very helpful. I am also allowing user to select 5 contacts so that they can send that edited text to these contacts. I am fetching these contacts from phonebook to the edit text. Can you please tell me how to save these contacts also ?

Comment: @bhanukaushik . saved preferences is a separate storage. If you save something to it, you must load from it again. So when you change the text, you save it to the storage. and when you load the app back up, you want to load what is stored, back into the text box. That extra line is what loads it from the storage and sets the textbox with it

Comment: @Doomsknight I don't know `autoSave` make? Because I don't initialize variables `autoSave`. And in other class `extends Services` how to call this values I was save? Thanks.

Comment: @VănLộc That was a typo. It should be "autoSave" which is a string name of the preference you wish to save/load. The following link may be more useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12074219/940834

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Well formated Shared Preference example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/).

What you have to do is In your onCreate() method:
Just put this:

```
message.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave", null));
```

Comment: can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong in this ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should put ur method to `afterTextChanged`
2. To get the result from shared preferences you should put code to onCreate method of your Activity or Fragment.

Code:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs.
prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

EditText message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
message.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter the shared preferences in afterTextChanged()