# Get string from one class to another class in Android?

Tags: android, string, getter-setter

I need to get the string variable from one class of my project to another class,

in First class, I made a string type variable and that is Global, like this:
the name of class is firstclass

```
 public String  firstClassVar;
```

and I am assigning the value to it in this method

```
public String requestForServerData(String strURL) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, IllegalArgumentException, Exception {
//additional code 
 firstClassVar   = myObject.getString("values");
//additional code
}
```

Now in second class, I am doing something like this:

```
  public firstclass getVar;

  public void method{
      String secondClassVar;
             secondClassVar=getVar.firstClassVar;
 }
```

By doing this it crashes. I have done another thing in firstclass that is

```
public String getStringPublically() {
       return firstClassVar;
    }
```

and for accessing it another class I am doing like this

```
   secondClassVar =getVar.getStringPublically();
```

and by doing this it also crashes the app.

Now I am bit new to Android, and don't know the basic way to access the string from another class.

Comment: You can pass the String to the method when you call it. Or store the string in stored preferences and retrieve from second location. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12074219/940834 You could also make the variable static if its appliciable. And access it directly. Or reference the instance of the class from the other class to access its variables

Comment: check change to static variable and call it as classname.its_name in other class. like "public static String  firstClassVar" .

Comment: @Doomsknight i will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SharedPreferences** to set/get values in any class you want.
[Here is a good topic about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3624280/3640637)

Answer (score 2):

Use `public static String  firstClassVar;` in First Class and in Second Class use `secondClassVar=FirstClass.firstClassVar;`

Comment: Easiest way ever.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

**pass values:**

```
Intent sendStuff = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
sendStuff.putExtra(key, stringvalue);
startActivity(sendStuff);
```

**getvalues:**

```
Intent startingIntent = getIntent();
String whatYouSent = startingIntent.getStringExtra(key, value);
```

IF it is Fragment

**Send:**

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putInt(key, value);
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Retrieve:**

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
 int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using putExtra and getExtra with Intent

Comment: i am using fragments, and there are issues of calling intents in fragments.. so i am not able t call an intent in fragments

Answer (score 0):

The app crashed because vetVar was not initialized. Try with

```
  public firstclass getVar = new firstclass();
```

in the second class