# service sending string to another activity without opening it

Tags: android, android-activity, view, android-service

I have a service that is working in the background - **SERVICE A**.
When I open an activity - **ACTIVITY A**, I want this service to change the text that is displayed on the editText field of this **ACTIVITY A**.
I thought that maybe if I get the context of the opened activity then I will be able to use and work on its Views. Is it possible?

Also a related question:
If I don't have the name of the field, can I use some loop to run and search for all the views in the activity and get its properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a less direct method would be preferred to getting this, rather than have the activity be directly updated by the service. In fact, in general Service/Activity communications are best handled in one of the following ways:

1. MessageHandlers- Basically, one can send a message to the other, which in turn the other sets the actions of the text.
2. BroadcastReceivers (LocalBroadcastReceiver is also okay)- One part sends a broadcast message to anyone listening, the other sets up a listener for that message. An Intent is passed, which can contain the message.

I would suggest that you use the second. The application sends a broadcast to the service upon opening, and the service returns a broadcast to pass the requested data to the Activity.

See also the [Service docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService) from the Android SDK.

Comment: is there anything to do if the activity is from a third party? I mean that I am not the developer of it.

Comment: That depends on the third party's API. In that case, you have to communicate with it using only public items. I suspect the feedback will be via a Broadcast Receiver in such case, but without seeing the API...

Answer (score 0):

1 save the string in preferences from service (see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12074248/4647577 )

2 retrieve the string when activity is created and set it to edittext

In your question you said that you want to show the string when you open the activity , so the 2 steps above will do the job .

For better performance you can repeat the second step in onresume();