# Shared Preferences for Arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I've a bunch of strings in an arraylist.

I want to save some of the strings in a shared preferences.

like if user selects a sting whose index is 3, I want to store that particular string in a shared preference.

Is it possible?

Please let me know.

Comment: please give me some idea..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074156/android-storing-retrieving-strings-with-shared-preferences

Answer (score 2):

I hope that this code will help you understand it

```
int id = selectedItemNum;

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Item1");
list.add("Item2");
list.add("Item3");
list.add("Item4");
String selectedString = list.get(id);

String APP_PREFERENCES = "savedStrings"; 
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("savedString"+id, selectedString);
editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

To save data to SharedPreferences:

```
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

   for(int i=0; i<arraylist.size(); i++){
      sharedPreferences.edit().putString("TAG" +  Integer.toString(i)
                                         ,arraylist.get(i)).apply();
    }
```

To get data from SharedPreferences:

```
   sharedPreferences.getString("TAG" + "x", null); x is a number position in array list
```