# SharedPreferences Android

Tags: java, android

I am having an app with 3 screens currently.

1 is a main screen with 6 buttons and 2 of which buttons have an intent to go to the other 2 screens.

1 of those screens is Themes. It has 6 layouts whose color of BG changes to white when clicked. It is fine but i need to save this preference of the user out of 6 and have it further used in my tic-tac-toe images..... all 6 themes will change tic-tac-toe pieces...thats my plan (*Mainly imageview imageresource change...thats all).

I want that whenever person closes that Themes Screen with selecting ... suppose say 2nd one...whenever he opens back the screen or app, it should show the 2nd one selected...which user can change...and therefore change the value.

I tried sharedPreferences but didnt worked. Can anyone plz help me a bit? Moreover how to change imageView resource based on which theme selected? Use SharedPreferences get() for that?

Do answer if you can help. It will be greatly appreciated.
Thanx in advance

Comment: Show what you tried with `SharedPreferences`. How you save the value, how you retrieve it and how you tried to use the retrieved value

Comment: what you tried with shared preferences and why it didn't worked?

Comment: share your SharedPreferences code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently wrote an example for `SharedPreferences`:

```
private static final String GLOBAL_PREFERENCES = "a.nice.identifier.for.your.preferences.goes.here";

public static void savePreferences(@NonNull Context context, String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(GLOBAL_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static int loadPreferences(@NonNull Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(GLOBAL_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

This is an example for saving and loading an integer from `SharedPreferences`.

These methods (and static final member variable) would be placed into a helper class called `Utils` for the examples below:

In your example, when the user changes the theme (and wants to save that) you can call `Utils.savePreferences(context, "theme", 1);`.

When the user returns to the App, you can use `int theme = Utils.loadPreferences(context, "theme", 0);` to return their selected theme (or 0 for default).

Comment: What is `Utils`? It is not stated anywhere that you have created a helper class. If you are doing it this raw, without reusing the `SharedPreferences` object you may as well do something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12074219/940834) directly

Comment: Utils would just be a helper class. If they are only writing one value, it isn't an issue.

Comment: I would clarify that above in the code example. +1 as it does work.