# giving NullPointerException when I getting data using sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

SharedPreferences code written in fragment class.This is my code

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

public void saveData(String name){
    Log.e("saved",name);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Text",name);
    editor.commit();
}
public String getData(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    String text = preferences.getString("Text", null);
    Log.e("save",text);
    return text;
}
```

This is how I am calling the getData() method from other activity

```
Stt stt = new Stt();
String name = stt.getData();
```

I do not understand the problem. Why I am getting nullpointerexception when I calling getData() method. I think my data is successfully store.When I checking using Log I am getting correct string back in saveData().

This is my log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity `ComponentInfo{com.example.kartikeya_pc.sample/com.example.kartikeya_pc.sample.NaturalLanguage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:371)
                                                                               at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:366)
                                                                               at com.example.kartikeya_pc.sample.Stt.getData(Stt.java:404)
                                                                               at com.example.kartikeya_pc.sample.NaturalLanguage.onCreate(NaturalLanguage.java:28)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
                                                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) `
                                                                           `
```

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074156/android-storing-retrieving-strings-with-shared-preferences

Comment: I have use this but still I'm getting same problem. I hve add my log after using this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getData` method,why not use :

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are writing to a different file and reading data from a different file

From the docs: if you use getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) you get a sharedpref file with the name of the reference activity.

> SharedPreferences getPreferences (int mode)
>
> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying
>   getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's
>   class name as the preferences name.

And with PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) you get altogether a different sharedpref file managed by framework.

> SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreferences (Context context)
>
> Gets a SharedPreferences instance that points to the default file that is used by the preference framework in the given context.