# Why does the swtich return to the initial phase?

Tags: java, android

I've created a `swich` and i'm saving the *boolean value* in to the `sharedPreferences`, but when i restore the activity the switch return to **OFF** while i want to keep it **ON** if it was turned **ON** while if it was turned **OFF** to keep it **OFF**.

Here's my **switch** code:

```
        buttonSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                switched = "ON";
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("SWTCH", buttonSwitch.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
            }else{
                switched = "OFF";
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("SWTCH", buttonSwitch.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is `onCreate` *SharedPreferences*:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyle", MODE_PRIVATE);
    buttonSwitch.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("SWTCH", false));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are accessing a completely different shared preference instance.

```
"com.example.xyle"
```

and

```
"com.example.xyz"
```

Please change them to be equal

Comment: Great, i didn't noticed that mistake that was the issue, ill accept the your answer in 9 minutes.

Comment: @I.Mytyuk No problem. You could consider using Default Shared Preferences. Rather than private, unless there is a specific reason for it. Also, `apply()` is better than `commit()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12074219/940834

Comment: @I.Mytyuk, to avoid such a situation try not to use inline strings, but use constants.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yep a good suggestion for the private preference route. Minimize typos where possible for resused strings.

Comment: @VladMatvienko sure i will, i'm just new in android so i still have much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

**Use same preference name for both reading and writing.**

You can also enhance onCheckedChanged to:

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                switched = isChecked ? "ON":"OFF";
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("SWTCH", isChecked);
                editor.commit();
        }
```