# How to Store JSON data in SharedPrefrence and access offline

Tags: android, json, android-studio

How to save the JSON in shared preference and fetch the value from local also the verse keeps updating every day, so the shared preference also need to check online for the updated content on how to implement this

public class VOTD_Data extends AsyncTask {

```
private String verseData = "";
private String dailyverse = "";
private String verseauthor = "";

private Context context;

public VOTD_Data(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://beta.ourmanna.com/api/v1/get/?format=json");

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = "";

        while (line != null){

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            verseData  = verseData + line;
        }


        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(verseData).getJSONObject("verse");
        JSONObject verseObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("details");



        dailyverse = verseObject.getString("text");
        verseauthor = verseObject.getString("reference");

        PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .edit()
                .putString("dailyverse", dailyverse)
                .putString("verseauthor", verseauthor)
                .apply();


    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    Fragment_Home.dailyVerse.setText(this.dailyverse);
    Fragment_Home.verseAuthor.setText(this.verseauthor);

}
}
```

Home Fragment

public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

```
    public static TextView dailyVerse;
    public static TextView verseAuthor;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        dailyVerse = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.daily_verse);
        verseAuthor = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.verse_author);


        //BindMethod
        fetchDailyVerseData();


        return rootView;
    }

    private void fetchDailyVerseData() {
//        VOTD_Data process = new VOTD_Data();
//        process.execute();

        new VOTD_Data(getContext()).execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        requireActivity().setTitle("Home");
    }


    private class VOTD_DATA extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())
                    .edit()
                    .putString("dailyverse", String.valueOf(dailyVerse))
                    .putString("verseauthor", String.valueOf(verseAuthor))
                    .apply();

            return null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: But I'm not able to use shared preference in ASync class :(

Comment: Im not sure how to do this, can you help me out. share some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a constructor to pass in the context.

```
public class VOTD_Data extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private String dailyverse;
    private String verseauthor;

    public VOTD_Data(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        dailyverse = sharedPreferences.getString("dailyverse", "");
        verseauthor = sharedPreferences.getString("verseauthor", "");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            ... // get dailyverse and verseauthor from network
            sharedPreferences
                .edit()
                .putString("dailyverse", dailyverse)
                .putString("verseauthor", verseauthor)
                .apply(); 
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
        Fragment_Home.dailyVerse.setText(dailyverse);
        Fragment_Home.verseAuthor.setText(verseauthor);
    }
}
```

In `fetchDailyVerseData()`, call `new VOTD_Data(getActivity()).execute();`.

See [Android - Storing/retrieving strings with shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074156/android-storing-retrieving-strings-with-shared-preferences)

Comment: Hi Lo Wai Kiu, Thank you so much for your response,  the code is still not working for me, I've updated the main Code above after implementation please check, also im passing to value to fragment is there a difference in code for activity and fragment. Please help :)

Comment: Hi Lo Wai Kiu Im really sorry to bother you so much, Its still not working for me :( im setting my text from onPostExecute so only that display, if there is not internet the Daily verse is not displaying :( Please help how can i achieve this. I want to store the Daily verse in sharedPrefrence and display the text, and if the JSON is updated the text in sharedPrefrence must need to be updated. How to do this, it would be really kind of you to share the code.

Comment: So you get strings from shared preferences first. If network fail you fall back to the stored strings.