# how to display nested json objects and array in two different activites in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, object, nested

I have one web service in which there are nested object and array, I have parsed the data in one activity, however I want to display the data in two different activity , how can I implement this?

Comment: If it's not too big a bit of JSON, you can store it in a sharedPreference as a String in the first activity and parse it in the second activity. Wouldn't recommend for large JSON files/strings though...

Comment: Okay, can you suggest any example from google, or share any link of that?

Comment: This SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12074219/959481) explains how to add and retrieve strings from sharedPrefs. After downloading the JSON, store the response in ActivityA, and when opening ActivityB, retrieve?

Comment: I've posted this as an answer. If it works for you, accept it and others will know it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This SO post ([Storing/retrieving strings with shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12074219/959481)) explains how to add and retrieve strings from sharedPrefs. After downloading the JSON in your web service, store the response in ActivityA, and when opening ActivityB, retrieve and parse the JSON using a method common to both activities.